# what is the best data for numbers

Tags: sql-server

Good day what is the best data type to use for numbers in SQL Server

Comment: You mean the data type which will take any numeric data

Comment: In my table for now is varchar(50)

Comment: If you store only **whole numbers** (1, 2, 42, 817), then use `INT` (or if these get really large, larger than 2 billion, use `BIGINT` instead). If you need to store **fractional numbers** (2.75, 2.2), use `DECIMAL(p,s)`. Try to avoid `FLOAT`, `REAL` or `DOUBLE` since those are inherently prone to rounding errors etc.

Comment: Some of those examples aren't numbers though. For example `'GL45R-2'` isn't a number. You won't be able to store those values in a numerical data type such as `int` or `decimal`.

Comment: is the DECIMAL(18,0) that,s what i find

Comment: so for gl45r i will stay on varchar(50)

Comment: and for letters like key

Comment: Please properly define the types of values you want to store, their range of values and what precision is required.

Comment: Il_raffa dont now what you dont understand but i dit go and edit my question hope it help you, ((Larnu help me good))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Your Data Types here

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php

Run the Below t-sql for more your data types as below

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE [Customer]
(
  [CustomerKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

  [Test_Number] [varchar](50) NULL

);

insert into Customer values (1,"25/08/2018");
insert into Customer values (2,15:06:59);
insert into Customer values (3,25.01);
insert into Customer values (4,"GL45R-2");


select * from Customer
```

Comment: now it tells me Error: near line 13: near ":06": syntax error, its this is wrong (insert into Customer values (2,15:06:59); so what must i put there ?/?-

Comment: it want (15-06-59) but that,s not what is in the data now i,m lost??

Comment: You can store it as a string under VARCHAR like  `" 15:06:59"`

Comment: OK and for text like the word KEY

Comment: yes, varchar will  support text format also

Comment: one last thing what data type can work for all text and numbers and what is best to allow Nulls or not.

Comment: Varchar is good choice and declare column as not null then it will work for both null and not null

Comment: If the answer helped you,You can mark this as best answer